# Spring integration outbound channel for Gemfire to store payload

Tags: spring-integration, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to send `payload` over to gemfire cache. I receive this `payload` as a MQ Message. It works fine if my `outbound adapter` is another `Queue`.

However when the outbound channel is outbound adapter for Gemfire it throws exception. Below is the code snippet.

Help here is really appreciated. As i am new to Gemfire + Spring IO

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="wMQ_in_channelAdapter" 
       concurrent-consumers="5"
       max-concurrent-consumers="10"
       connection-factory="inCachingConnectionFactory"           
       destination="requestQueue-mq"
       extract-payload="true"
       channel="demoChannel"/>


<integration:channel id="demoChannel"/>

<integration:service-activator input-channel="demoChannel" 
            ref="demoBean"
            method="upperCase"
            output-channel="orchestrationChannel" /> 

<integration:channel id="orchestrationChannel"/>

<gfe:cache id="PushProducer" cache-xml-location="classpath:PushProducer.xml"/>

<gfe:lookup-region id="exampleRegion" cache-ref="PushProducer" name="exampleRegion"/> 

<int-gfe:outbound-channel-adapter id="cacheChannel" channel="orchestrationChannel" region="exampleRegion">
        <int-gfe:cache-entries>
            <entry key="payload" value="abcd"/>
        </int-gfe:cache-entries> 
</int-gfe:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Below is the error i am seeing when the message is received in the application

```
[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3][org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
```

The `payload` is printed here in above line.. and the below line is the error

```
12:20:00.196 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3][org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:302)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.send(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:479)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:620)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractMethodError` is usually because of a classpath problem (version mismatch).

In this case, it looks like you are using `spring-integration-core` 4.x and `spring-integration-gemfire` 3.x (or earlier); or vice-versa.

In 4.0, the signature of that method changed (different `Message` object).

I suggest you use 4.1.2 for everything.

Comment: sorry for the late reply guys, But was busy with some other stuff. It turns out that it was a version issue, with Spring 3.x.x i needed to downgrade the gemfire dependancy from version 7.0.1 to 6.X.X and it worked fine.  Thanks for you help gusy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all not enough info in the stacktrace. There is no points regarding `CacheWritingMessageHandler`.

From other side see this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/gemfire.html#gemfire-outbound. So, your `<entry key="payload" value="abcd"/>` isn't valid, because both `key` and `value` must be SpEL expressions. Since the root evaluation object is `Message` there is no such a getter `getAbcd()` on the `Message` object.

Comment: @ Artem,in the stack trace i do see below entry regarding 'CacheWritingMessageHandler' {'DEBUG org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-5][org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage'} after the entry it prints the entire payload and then throws that exception message i copied in the above question. BTW, i tried with value as 'payload.toLowerCase()' still the same exception. what is missing the stacktrace isnt giving any hints

Comment: thats my pom dependancies , anything wrong ?
{<groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
<groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
<groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-integration-gemfire</artifactId> 
<version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
<groupId>com.gemstone.gemfire</groupId>  
<artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>  
<version>7.0.1</version>  
</dependency> }

Comment: Would be better if you debug the `CacheWritingMessageHandler#handleMessageInternal` to determine the root of cause.

Comment: Oh, I see, but check the real classpath run with `-verbose` to see which jar each class is loaded from (see my answer) - or look at the dependency tree with maven in case something is overriding the version - in future don't put stuff like this in comments; it's hard to see - edit your question instead when adding code/config - don't put it in a comment.